# ag-grid - how to get parent node from child grid via context menu?

Tags: ag-grid

As an example, I have a [Master\Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/) grid.

> Master\Detail defined as `key-relation` model and on `getDetailRowData` method *parent node data* exists in `params`
>   [image]

but how to get *parent node data* from child view?

> Tried via context-menu:

On right click -  `getContextMenuItems` got executed which has an input `params` 
[image]

On this sample, child-grid doesn't have any row and `node` in context-params is null, it's ok, 
**but anyway it should be possible to retrieve the parent details at least via grid API, isn't it ?**

Then I've tried to get `parent` via node:
[image]
but instead of `detail_173` as you can see its `ROOT_NODE_ID`, and here is a confusion for me.

So question is that how to get parent node data (RecordID 173 just in case) through child-view context menu or any other possible way (without storing temp value, cuz multiple children's could be opened at the same time)

Yes, I've read this part [Accessing Detail Grid API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/#accessing-detail-grid-api), and still unclear how to get parent-node via child-grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very reliable solution is to create your own **detailCellRenderer**.

on the `init` method:

```
this.masterNode = params.node.parent;
```

when creating the detail grid:

```
detailGridOptions = {
    ...
    onCellClicked: params => console.log(this.masterNode.data)
}
```

Here is a plunker demonstrating this:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/8EIHpxQnlxsqe7EO

Answer (score 7):

For React Hook users without access to lifecycle methods, use Ag-Grid Context to pass the parent node (or parent data) to the detail grid via detailGridOptions. No need to traverse the DOM or use a detailCellRenderer unless you want to :)

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context/

```
detailCellRendererParams: (masterGridParams) => ({
    detailGridOptions: {
        ...
        context: { 
            masterGrid: {
                node: masterGridParams.node.parent, 
                data: masterGridParams.data 
            } 
        },
        onCellClicked: detailGridParams => {
            console.log(detailGridParams.context.masterGrid.node);
            console.log(detailGridParams.context.masterGrid.data);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm kind of surprised some form of this isn't wired up by default.

Answer (score 3):

Able to achieve it. Have a look at the plunk I've created: [Get master record from child record - Editing Cells with Master / Detail](https://plnkr.co/edit/ncbGDpHE50ZwHoweOzJB?p=preview)

> Right click on any child grid's cell, and check the console log. You'll be able to see parent record in the log for the child record on which you've click.

---

The implementation is somewhat tricky. We need to traverse the DOM inside our component code. Luckily [ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) has provided us the access of it.

1. Get the child grid's wrapper HTML node from the `params` - Here in the code, I get it as the 6th element of the `gridOptionsWrapper.layoutElements` array.
2. Get it's 3rd level parent element - which is the actual `row` of the parent. Get it's `row-id`.
3. Use it to get the row of the parent grid using parent grid's `gridApi`.

```
  getContextMenuItems: (params): void => {
      var masterId = params.node.gridOptionsWrapper.layoutElements[6]
            .parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('row-id');
      // get the parent's id
      var id = masterId.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
      console.log(id);
      var masterRecord = this.gridApi.getRowNode(id).data;
      console.log(masterRecord);
    },
    defaultColDef: { editable: true },
    onFirstDataRendered(params) {
      params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
```

*Note: Master grid's `rowId`s are defined with `[getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"` assuming that `account` is the primary key of the parent grid.*

Comment: try to open multiple and play with context-menu first\second\third, you will get not expected result

Comment: I've updated the plunk. check the link. and yes, I can see the parent records are logged properly. could you mention the exact steps?

Comment: `[getRowNodeId]="getRowNodeId"` - yep in my case its like that :`return data.RecordID`;
so, seems your sample works. 
tried also `api.gridOptionsWrapper.layoutElements[6]
            .parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('row-id')` - seems correct;
one of dirtiest hack as i've ever used )

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me (with agGrid v22).   There *is* no 6th layoutElement to query.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot in finding a solution to this problem without creating custom details renderer but I could not find any viable solution. So the real good solution is already answered. I am just trying to share another way to avoid creating custom renderer.

So What I did is that I changed the details data on the fly and added the field I required from the parent.

```
getDetailRowData: function (params: any) {
      params?.data?.children?.forEach((child:any) => {
        //You can assign any other parameter.
        child.parentId= params?.data?.id;
      });
      params.successCallback(params?.data?.children);
}
```

When you expand the row to render details the method `getDetailRowData` gets called, so it takes in params as the current row for which we are expanding the details and the details table is set by invoking `params.successCallback`. So before setting the row data I am iterating and updating the parentId.

Answer (score 0):

**Improving hinsenchan's answer**

The basic idea here is to embed the context object and then access the master grid data.

For this answer, I'm using the example from this question: [Access master record from detail table with AG Grid master detail view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76671521/access-master-record-from-detail-table-with-ag-grid-master-detail-view/76712623#76712623)

**Vanilla Javascript Answer**

Our detailCellRendererParams have the context object. This is where we embed our master grid reference; params

```
detailCellRendererParams: (params) => {
  var res = {};
  res.detailGridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'firstName' },
      { field: 'lastName' },
      {
        headerName: 'Actions',
        showRowGroup: 'role',
        filter: false,
        valueGetter: ({ data }) => data,
        cellRenderer: CustomUserCell,
        minWidth: 160,
      },
    ],
    context: {
      params: params, // the master grid reference
    },
  };
  res.getDetailRowData = (params) => {
    params.successCallback(params.data.users);
  };
  return res;
},
```

Now we can access the master grid data from our custom cell renderer component

```
class CustomUserCell {
  constructor() {
    CustomUserCell.prototype.__init.call(this);
  }

  __init() {
    this.onClick = (event) => {
      alert(`Role Id is ${event.currentTarget.roleId}`);
    };
  }

  init({ node, columnApi, ...rest }) {
    console.log('node', node);
    console.log('columnApi', columnApi);
    console.log('rest', rest); // attention here

    this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
    this.eButton = document.createElement('button');
    this.eButton.roleId = rest.context.params.data.roleId; // roleId from the master grid reference
    this.eButton.addEventListener('click', this.onClick);
    this.eButton.innerHTML = 'Role Id';
    this.eGui.appendChild(this.eButton);
  }

  getGui() {
    return this.eGui;
  }

  refresh(params) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Here's the main.js file

```
/** @type {import('ag-grid-community').GridOptions} */

const MOCK_DATA = [
  {
    roleId: 1,
    roleName: 'Role 1',
    users: [
      {
        userId: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    roleId: 2,
    roleName: 'Role 2',
    users: [
      {
        userId: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
      },
      {
        userId: 2,
        firstName: 'Jane',
        lastName: 'Doe',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const gridOptions = {
  rowData: MOCK_DATA,
  columnDefs: [
    {
      headerName: 'Role',
      field: 'roleName',
      valueGetter: ({ data }) =>
        `${data ? data.roleName : ''} (${data ? data.users.length : 0})`,
      filter: false,
      sort: 'asc',
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
    },
    { headerName: 'Role Id', field: 'roleId' },
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  masterDetail: true,
  detailCellRendererParams: (params) => {
    var res = {};
    res.detailGridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'firstName' },
        { field: 'lastName' },
        {
          headerName: 'Actions',
          showRowGroup: 'role',
          filter: false,
          valueGetter: ({ data }) => data,
          cellRenderer: CustomUserCell,
          minWidth: 160,
        },
      ],
      context: {
        params: params,
      },
    };
    res.getDetailRowData = (params) => {
      params.successCallback(params.data.users);
    };
    return res;
  },
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

**Result**

[image: Requested Scene]

Here's the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/DguO7RIujVPII845?preview

Here's the react equivalent: https://plnkr.co/edit/KCjAY6ZeAH77040c?preview

Here's the vue equivalent: https://plnkr.co/edit/u3beMrWk5DTJ2RiH?preview

Here's the angular equivalent: https://plnkr.co/edit/X9UykggB5lZGpijV?preview