# How to get specific row from "detail table" when a row clicked (in ag-grid Master/Detail )

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I use ag-grid Master/Detail component. 
I want to define click event on detail table, so that when a row was clicked, access to fields of clicked row (in order to show row fields in a Modal). Do me a favor by answering this question.

Comment: add what you have tried by editing the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get parent node from child grid via context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722447/how-to-get-parent-node-from-child-grid-via-context-menu)

Comment: Hope you'll get your answer with the above link. Go through [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). If you think that's not the question you're looking for, edit the question or create new one providing more information and code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add function on output event for your grid.
`(cellClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"`
And handler:

```
onRowClicked(params) {
    params.node.setExpanded(!params.node.expanded);
}
```